# Can I create a stored procedure in serverless sql pool

Tags: azure, serverless, pool

Following the official documentation from Microsoft, it is possible to create a stored procedure in Azure Synapse Serverless SQL pool. I manage to execute the following script

```
Create proc Test
as
Select 1 as X
```

However, I Don't see the Test stored procedure in the Serverless SQL pool.
I don't also see the programmability folder in the Serverless SQL pool

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've found to view the Stored Procedure in Synapse Studio or Azure Data Studio is to query the sys schema tables.  However SPs are visible if you use SSMS via steps here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/get-started-ssms

**Query in Synapse Studio**

```
SELECT definition, uses_ansi_nulls, uses_quoted_identifier, is_schema_bound  
FROM sys.sql_modules  
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Test');   
GO
```

[image]

**SSMS**

[image]